# Checking for null pointer exception in an array in Jenkins scripted pipeline method

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am injecting Active Choices parameter value(s) in the Jenkins scripted pipeline.

PFB sample values passed to active choice parameter block:

```
return['ABC','DEF','GHI',JKL']
```

PFB my sample script:

```
node(){
    selectModName()
}

def selectModName(){
    stage 'Multi selection'
    String[] mods = "${modName}".split(',')
    modsz = mods.size()
    echo ''+modsz+''
    for(mod in mods){
        if (modsz == null || modsz == 0){
            echo 'There is nothing to be printed'
        } else {
            echo ''+mod+' is name of the module \n'
        }
    }
}
```

The `else` block is executed when I pass greater than or equal to 1 value(s) (working as intended). But `if` block is not executing its logic when I don't pass any parameter and press build now.

Funny thing is- `size()` is returning `1` instead of `0` (`echo ''+modsz+''`) when values aren't passed.

How to make `if` block execute its logic when no values are passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code always jumps to the "else" block, because

```
"".split(',')
```

produces an array with a single empty string.

```
assert "".split(',').size() == 1
assert "".splti(',') == [""] as String[]
```

When you use active choice parameter with multiple values selection and you don't select anything, your variable name stores an empty string. You should check first if the `modName` parameter is not an empty string and only otherwise split and display values.

```groovy
node(){
    selectModName()
}

def selectModName(){
    stage 'Multi selection'

    if (modName) {
        String[] mods = modName?.split(',')
        for (mod in mods) {
            echo " ${mod} is name of the module"
        }
    } else {
        echo 'There is nothing to be printed'
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer has worked. I had to make only one change. Instead of modName?, I had to use “${modName}?.